# Get top 10 frequent table entites which were max two days old?

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

This is my mySql table "listazelja":
http://prntscr.com/duj2tf

i want to get what is mentioned in title with this code in my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\ListaZelja;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class GlazbeniController extends Controller
{
    public function listazelja(){

        $sada = Carbon::now();

        $listaZelja = DB::table('listazelja')->orderBy('zapis_count','desc')->select(DB::raw('count(*) as zapis_count'),'zapis_id')
            ->groupBy('zapis_id')
            ->having($sada->diffInHours(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H-m-s', 'created_at')) <= 48)
            ->take(10)->get();

        return view('pregledajlistuzelja',compact('listaZelja'));
    }
}
```

This is error I am getting:

*InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 425:
A four digit year could not be found
Data missing*

I know that problem is with this line of code:
 `->having($sada->diffInHours(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H-m-s', 'created_at')) <= 48)`

so what should I do to make it work.

P.S. created_at in mySql is of type: timestamp

Comment: I think 'created_at' is just being passed as a string since you're calling it within $sada. PS. This is why I hate frameworks.

Comment: Try using Mysql NOW() function and INTERVAL or TiMEDIFF...

Comment: In `Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $time, $tz);` the second argument must be a `$time` but you are passing a string with the value of `created_at`. Extracted from `Carbon` doc `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H', '1975-05-21 22')->toDateTimeString(); // 1975-05-21 22:00:00`

Comment: @EddyTheDove's answer seems ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your query like:

```
$twoDaysOldDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('now -48 hours'));
$listaZelja = DB::table('listazelja')
           ->orderBy('zapis_count','desc')
           ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as zapis_count'),'zapis_id')
           ->groupBy('zapis_id')
           ->whereDate('created_at', '<=', $twoDaysOldDate)
           ->take(10)
           ->get();
```

Hope this work for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$maxhours = Carbon::now()->subHours(48)->toDateTimeString();
$listaZelja = DB::table('listazelja')
            ->orderBy('zapis_count','desc')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as zapis_count'),'zapis_id')
            ->groupBy('zapis_id')
            ->having('created_at' <= maxhours)
            ->take(10)->get();
```

Comment: Except missing "$" at maxhours something else doesnt work either.But, thanx anyways. :)